# Travis deploy script multiline command

Tags: travis-ci

I have following deploy script in Travis file and facing problem with multiline command. I've tried lots of combination and couldn't find a proper solution. If I extract it to the file and call it from script attribute, it works properly but our aim is to put all the commands in the script attribute as multiline command.

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: mvn deploy -B -DskipTests -Dbuild.number="$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
    on:
      tags: false
      branch: dev

  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script:
      pip install something &&
      another-command &&
      yet-another-command &&
      docker push "image-name"
    on:
      tags: false
      all_branches: true
```

Here is the error logs:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected
```

If someone knows how to define multiline commands, I will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try one of these options:

**Option 1:** Create your `deploy.sh` script, and call it from `.travis.yml`. I like this option, since it will make life easier - since you can test and run it separately, and avoid this exact issue that you are facing.

**Option 2:** If you insist on having the commands only in `.travis.yml` - you can try one of these syntax changes:

a: Try either `|` or `>` in the `script:` definition (to denote multiline text):

```
script: >
  pip install something &&
  another-command &&
  yet-another-command &&
  docker push "image-name"
```

b: Try providing the `script` as an array (assuming Travis supports this syntax here as well - as it is supported in many of their other options):

```
script: 
  - pip install something
  - another-command
  - yet-another-command
  - docker push "image-name"
```

Comment: using | or > syntax, it had a new line at the end of the commands. Make sure to start with 
>- or |-

Answer (score 5):

### TLDR

The example you gave in description looks legit from a YAML perspective. Please make sure you don't have empty lines or comments which prevents the content in script section from becoming one string

### Longer version

The `script` provider in deploy requires the script content being single string. Only one line is allowed so you can't use YAML array.

This is **different** from the [top level `script` section](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#customizing-the-build-phase). Top level `script` section allows you to use YAML array which means you can supply multiple single line strings leading with `-`

Having that said, any YAML single line (without line ending) can be used properly in deploy's script section. Here are some examples

```
script: pip install something &&
      another-command &&
      yet-another-command &&
      docker push "image-name"
```

```
# >- to removing the ending new line
script: >-
      pip install something &&
      another-command &&
      yet-another-command &&
      docker push "image-name"
```

The example below will **not work** for deploy's script section, but will **work** for top level script section

```
# Only works in top level script not deploy script
script:
    - pip install something && another-command
    - yet-another-command
    - docker push "image-name"
```